# How will an online MBA be perceived in applications for a faculty position in economics and accounting?

Tags: faculty-application, economics, business-school, online-degree

I recently retired and want to get back into pursuing higher education.

I am happily married and live in Los Angeles.  So, I am somewhat geographically constrained concerning my choice of MBA programs to attend.

I have now seriously considered online MBA programs, but I'm worried about the quality and perception and other potential risks of online degrees.

Another obstacle I face is that my employer will likely say that I was not a "team player" or a "good leader" for their organization.  Since MBA programs require so much teamwork and group projects and leadership skills, I don't think I am a good fit for traditional programs, hence the online programs would be better suited for me.

Can anyone provide some general comments about going the online MBA route?
I wish to become an Assistant Professor of Economics and Accounting.  So, I want to know how an online MBA will impact future employment in academia.

Comment: Would you please clarify _I recently retired_ and _my employer_?

Comment: It will take you out of consideration for any faculty appointment. MBAs are headed to industry; to teach, you need a relevant Ph.D. This doesn't depend on whether your program is online or not.

Comment: @scaahu: I assume OP means their former employer. An MBA application typically has letters by former supervisors, peers, and such (I've written those myself for such applicants). See, e.g., [here](http://www.usnews.com/education/articles/2010/12/17/get-into-business-school-letters-of-recommendation).

Comment: @gnometorule Sounds like an answer. Can you post it as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take you out of consideration for any faculty appointment. MBAs are headed to industry; to teach (be hired on tenure track), you need a relevant Ph.D. This doesn't depend on whether your program is online or not.

Come to think of it, depending on how interesting and high-level your prior job was, and if teaching (as opposed to research) interests you, you could target an [adjunct position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_professor) instead.